# Append child to existing array in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a json array (as a result of an activity):

```
{
    "name": "Union",
    "value": [
        {
            "branch": [
                {
                    "origin": "CAPUA",
                    "engineId": 398001,
                    "registration": "WEOIWEIJOKDFIJ09092309",
                    
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    
    ]
}
```

I want to append to this existing array a new child element **filterId** and its value.
For this purpose I have used a SerVariable, with the following formula:`@union(array(activity('GetEngines').output),array(concat('"filterId":',variables('fltr'))))`
However the output I get is :

```
{
    "name": "Union",
    "value": [
        {
            "branch": [
                {
                    "origin": "CAPUA",
                    "engineId": 398001,
                    "registration": "WEOIWEIJOKDFIJ09092309",
                    
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "\"filterId\":398291"
    ]
}
```

Which is not what I am looking for. I want to insert the "filterId":398291 underneath "engineId": 398001, in the existing array.
Does anyone have an idea on how this could be achieved easier?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add a new key-value pair ("filterId": 398291) to the existing JSON structure under the "branch" array. The issue is with the way you're using the concat function. Instead of appending a new array element, it's adding a string element to the array.

To achieve what you want, you can use the following approach:
{
"name": "Union",
"value": [
{
"branch": [
{
"origin": "CAPUA",
"engineId": 398001,
"registration": "WEOIWEIJOKDFIJ09092309",
"_elements": {
"self": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001"
},
"children": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001/children"
},
"entity": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001"
},
"filterId": 398291
}
}
]
}
]
}
It looks like you're trying to add a new key-value pair ("filterId": 398291) to the existing JSON structure under the "branch" array. The issue is with the way you're using the concat function. Instead of appending a new array element, it's adding a string element to the array.

To achieve what you want, you can use the following approach:

json

{
"name": "Union",
"value": [
{
"branch": [
{
"origin": "CAPUA",
"engineId": 398001,
"registration": "WEOIWEIJOKDFIJ09092309",
"_elements": {
"self": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001"
},
"children": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001/children"
},
"entity": {
"href": "https://api.tttttt.com/CAPUA/398001"
},
"filterId": 398291
}
}
]
}
]
}

Assuming you have a variable named fltr with the value 398291, you can use the following formula to achieve the desired result:
@union(
array(
activity('GetEngines').output
),
array(
json(
'{
"branch": [
{
"_elements": {
"filterId": ' + variables('fltr')
}
}
]
}'
)
)
)
This formula uses the json function to create a JSON structure for the new element with "filterId" and its value, and then uses @union to combine it with the existing array obtained from the 'GetEngines' activity. This should add the new element as a child of the existing "branch" array.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it won't let me use + variables('fltr')